# Error Building Container Image with Dockerfile to Serve Flask Web App

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, web-applications

I'm a beginner to flask web development and I'm trying to deploy my first app. Currently, I'm following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/serve-a-flask-app/

I'm pretty sure I've made all the necessary downloads and installations for this to work correctly.

I've followed the instructions so far, but I get stuck on the part where it says to build the container image using docker. It says to execute this command in the directory:
`docker build -t flask-container .`
I get this error: Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory.

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install docker? That error means the docker server is not running. What OS are you using to build the image?

Answer (score 0):

You docker engine is not running.
Install docker if necessary and start it.
Also make sure you are in the correct folder where your dockerFile resides